# Unable to copy code in Jekyll website

Tags: syntax, copy, jekyll, syntax-highlighting

I recently set up my blog on [abhitopia.com](http://abhitopia.com). The issue I am facing is that all the code I write in my blog (in markdown) cannot be copied. For instance, go to 
http://abhitopia.com/machine%20learning/2016/05/22/tensor_flow_exploration.html

You will be unable to copy code. I have already tried googling this. It is definitely not a feature that comes pre configured with Jekyll. I don't understand why. :(

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. Where do you want to copy the file from? Where to? How are you copying it?

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to how Jekyll is building your site. This is a problem with the theme that you are using ([Grayscale](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/)), which gives you the impression that you cannot select text in your code blocks.

If you look at your [grayscale.css file around line 409](https://github.com/abhitopia/abhitopia.github.io/blob/master/css/grayscale.css#L409), you'll see something like this:

[image]

These two styles are removing the shadow that one sees when selecting text, which makes you think you cannot copy the text.

Remove these two styles, or modify them, so that the shadow is visible and in a color you like. Alternatively, you can use a different theme, instead of that one.